# How to efficiently trigger events in Java according to date?

Tags: java, date, triggers, calendar, listener

I am building a relatively complex app for a company that keeps track of several objects and triggers events according to the object's age or preset dates contained in it.

For example:

Object object_A contains a "renewal date". When the renewal date and the system date coincide, the application needs to run a particular routine.

My question is: Since there will be thousands of such objects, what is the most efficient way of keeping track of all of them and triggering the respective routines at the respective dates and times?

Worth mentioning that I've used Calendar objects for describing these dates (though they can easily be converted into Date objects, so that's not entirely relevant).

I'd appreciate any pointing into the right direction...

Comment: Does the renewal date have to be owned by the objects?  Can you, instead, build a separate service designed to track objects, their renewal dates, and perform renewals?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org/) is an excellent library for robust/complex task scheduling.

Comment: Thank you. I'll look into that as soon as I can.

Answer (score 2):

I will encourage you (since you say you're building the app) to reconsider about responsibilities. I don't think it should be object responsibility to maintain that renewal date. I mean you can do it that way and has an agent that will periodically visit those items to see if its renewal date is today.

But, if you think as an external agent that will contain a renewal dates table it will be more efficient since:

1. All objects' triggers with same renewal date will fire at the same time.
2. Managing the check logic will be centralized
3. Cost (in space) of storing renewal date will reduce if collapse into a same date.

This is a big picture view but hopes it serves.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input! I'll think about that, although the design has already been agreed upon.